# Unique value in field for specific field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a new table in `SQL`, but I have a problem.

I want to have a unique value in one field but only for a specific field in same table, similar like a one to many.

```
Table:
ID_Order 
Supplier 
ID_Supplier_Order
```

And now I want to have ID_Order unique for the table, and ID_Supplier_Order only for specific Supplier. Can I do it in one table, or I have to create a second for Suppliers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add unique constraint to combination of two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800250/add-unique-constraint-to-combination-of-two-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from:

[Add unique constraint to combination of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800250/add-unique-constraint-to-combination-of-two-columns)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_yourtablename
  ON dbo.yourtablename(column1, column2);
```