# Unique constraint on two foreign keys to always be a different combination

Tags: sql-server, database, mssql-jdbc

I have a table named Followers which contains one PK column and two FK columns which will store integers of the table named User. However i dont want to have replicated values in columns - the combination of two FKs needs to always be different. How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add unique constraint to combination of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800250/add-unique-constraint-to-combination-of-two-columns)

Comment: Without DDL and a clear description of your requirement, only guessing is possible. Do you consider the set of values (1, 2) different from (2, 1) - ignoring your identity primary key column?

Answer (score 2):

Create a single unique key for both the columns

Answer (score 2):

A unique [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) or [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) will solve your problem. Unique constraints are implemented as unique indexes behind the scenes, so your selection of either solution is trivial.

To demonstrate, let's assume the following contrived scenario.

```
create table User (
  Id int identity primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null
);
go

create table Follower (
  Id int identity primary key,
  UserId int foreign key references User(Id),
  FollowerId int foreign key references User(Id)
);
go
```

To ensure the uniqueness of `UserId` & `FollowerId` add the following unique index.

```
create unique index ux_follower_userid_followerid
  on Follower
  (
    UsrId
    ,FollowerId
  );
go
```

> Note that it's generally advisable to also include non-clustered indexes on foreign key columns to facilitates joins.