# Entity Framework Core 5.0: ensure two columns cannot have the same value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity:

```
Item{
   Id,
   Barcode,
   UnitBarcode
}
```

I wand both columns 'Barcode' and 'UnitBarcode' be unique, that there are no equal'UnitBarcode' and 'Barcode' in any rows, like this table below:

| Id | Barcode | UnitBarcode | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1234 | allowed |
| 2 | 1234 | 5687 | not allowed |
| 3 | 5896 | 123 | not allowed |
| 4 | 123 | 798965 | not allowed |

Is there a way to implement this in EF Core 5.0 with Sql Server?

Comment: You simply want to add a UNIQUE constraint to a PAIR of columns, like this: `ALTER TABLE dbo.yourtablename
  ADD CONSTRAINT uq_yourtablename UNIQUE(column1, column2);`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800279/421195, or a unique index, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021965/421195

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

How to set keys in EF